# by simulating the command shell in java how to execute a file?

Tags: java, shell, cmd, command

I made a program that simulates the command shell (cmd), and it works as perfect as it should as i made it using threads so the user can write a new command without blocking the shell.

But, right now iam trying to creat a command (Showerrlog), whenever the user types this command he is supposed to be able to see the wrong commands that he or she tried to execute  during the last session.

for doing that iam using ( file handler ) that will creat a new .log file in each new session. But, unfortunatly iam still unable to open the last log file which contains the error commands. I dont know why!!

please take a look at my code and feel free to correct me :

```
package witheyul;

import static com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Utility.printStackTrace;
import com.sun.javafx.tk.FileChooserType;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import static java.lang.Compiler.command;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder;

/**
 *
 * @author ad
 */
public class WithEyul implements Runnable {
    int x = 0;
    String command;
    public WithEyul(String command){
        this.command = command;
    }

    @Override

    public void run(){
          List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(command);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            input.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
        }
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(input);
        // ProcessBuilder creates a process corresponding to the input command
        // now start the process
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            Process proc = pb.start();
            // obtain the input and output streams
            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            // read what the process returned
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {


              try {
                  System.err.println("Error");


                  // try {
                  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Testing");
                  FileHandler fh;
                  fh = new FileHandler("E:/MyLogFile.log");
                  logger.addHandler(fh);
                  SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
                  fh.setFormatter(formatter);
                  logger.info(command);
                     }
                    catch (SecurityException e){
                  printStackTrace();

                  while (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Showerrlog")){
                      try {

                          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\MyLogFile.log");

                      } catch (IOException ex) {
                          Logger.getLogger(WithEyul.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                      }
                  }

              } catch (IOException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(WithEyul.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(WithEyul.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }



    }

    }
```

and here is the main method class:

```
package witheyul;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

/**
 *
 * @author ad
 */
public class TestProcessBuilder {

    static void createProcess(String command) throws java.io.IOException {
      Thread t = new Thread (new WithEyul(command));
      t.start();

        }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        String commandLine;
        File wd;
        BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("\n\n***** Welcome to the Java Command Shell *****");
        System.out.println("If you want to exit the shell, type END and press RETURN.\n");
        // we break out with â€˜ENDâ€™
        while (true) {
            // show the Java shell prompt and read what command they entered
            System.out.print("jsh>");
            commandLine = console.readLine();
            // if user entered a return, just loop again
            if (commandLine.equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            if (commandLine.toLowerCase().equals("end")) { //User wants to end shell
                System.out.println("\n***** Command Shell Terminated. See you next time. BYE for now. *****\n");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            createProcess(commandLine);


            }
        }
    }
```

i beleive that i have something wrong her but iam not sure :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\MyLogFile.log");
```

but how else to fix it ?

Best regards ..

Answer (score 3):

To open a file in the default editor you can't use `Runtime.exec`, you have to use `Desktop.open`

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("E:\\MyLogFile.log"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but i have no idea why when iam writing ( Showerrlog) 

iam getting an error !!

Comment: Error
sep 18, 2014 8:25:00 EM witheyul.WithEyul run
INFO: Showerrlog

am getting the same error as am writing any other invalid code ,, 
 

i think i havee somthing wrong here 
if (command.contentEquals("Showerrlog"))

Comment: @user3526756 Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: ***** Welcome to the Java Command Shell *****
If you want to exit the shell, type END and press RETURN.

jsh>Showerrlog
Error
sep 18, 2014 8:34:58 EM witheyul.WithEyul run
INFO: Showerrlog
jsh>

Comment: i will get the same error if i write for example (hshedw)  or any other invalid shell command ..

i wonder if me intializing the ( Showerrlog ) as ..

if (command.contentEquals("Showerrlog")) 

was right or wrong ?

Comment: @user3526756 That's because you are trying to execute is as a process before checking if it is "Showerrorlog". Move that check _before_ creating the process and it will work

Comment: thanks alot it works perfectly now!! 

but last point, as you can see iam using file handler !! 

and by default, the file handler will create a new log with every new time i run the code and write wrong commands. 

the question is how to execute the right log file which is related to last operation ? 

for exampel 

if am running the code for the 6th time, the log file will be named ( MyLogFile.log.6 ) 

how to run that one ,,?

regards ,,

Comment: i tried to make for loop with int i, but then the program is not taking any command its just looping for nothing !!